# TCPDF giving broken characters

Tags: php, pdf, unicode, fonts, tcpdf

some of specific bangla characters are broken in tcpdf output. I used nikosh, sansserif fonts. but all of them are given same output. no change.

```
require_once('tcpdf.php');  
  $obj_pdf = new TCPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);  
  $obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);  
  $obj_pdf->SetTitle("টেবিল ডাটা");  
  $obj_pdf->SetHeaderData('', '', PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);  
  $obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));  
  $obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));  
  $obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('nikosh');  
  $obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);  
  $obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, '5', PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);  
  $obj_pdf->setPrintHeader(false);  
  $obj_pdf->setPrintFooter(false);  
  $obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10);  
  $obj_pdf->SetFont('nikosh', '', 14);  
  $obj_pdf->AddPage(); 
  /*if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/fonts/freeserif.php')) {
        require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/fonts/freeserif.php');
        $obj_pdf->setLanguageArray('kiron');
    } */
  $content = '';  
  $content .= '  
  <h3 align="center">Table Data</h3><br /><br />  
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">  
       <tr>  
            <th width="5%">ID</th>  
            <th width="30%">Name</th>  
            <th width="10%">Gender</th>  
            <th width="45%">Designation</th>  
            <th width="10%">Age</th>  
       </tr>  
  ';  
  $content .= fetch_data();  
  $content .= '</table>';  
  $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);  
  $obj_pdf->Output('sample.pdf', 'I');  }
```

TCPDF output screenshot:
[image: this is orginal output]

expected output:
[image: expected output]

Comment: can you show the codes that you have tried and explain it further.

Comment: please check I added the code.

Comment: Works for me. Bengali is covered by Arial Unicode MS on my system. I don't have nikosh, so I commented out those lines.

Comment: I tried using Arial Unicode MS . still same problem. can you please paste your code here.

Comment: @daxim can u please share your code?